# How to install ibus typing booster?

Tags: software-installation, ibus

How to install ibus typing booster?

The homepage has no docs for ubuntu installation: http://www.typingbooster.org/howtoinstall/

The package request on debian was not done: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=729851

How can I get this running on ubuntu?

I want to use it for english and german texts.

Comment: mention your Ubuntu version

Comment: I use LTS of year 2014. I would update to a newer version if necessary.

Comment: According to launchpad, it is available in 15.04: https://launchpad.net/ibus-typing-booster

Comment: so upgrade to Vivid (15.04) and install your app :) as you said you would.

Comment: Before updating my ubuntu I want to be sure that it works. There something very strange here: https://launchpad.net/ibus-typing-booster There are only links to a package called "predict". But this is a "Satellite Tracking Program with Optional Voice Output". I don't understand it ....

Comment: Did it work on version 15.04 ?