# install ibus-typing-booster on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation, ibus

I tried [ibus-typing-booster](https://fedorahosted.org/ibus-typing-booster/) software on fedora. Is this available for Ubuntu?

This is really useful software that I will like to use.

---

Update:

I tried to install it using the following steps. But got an error:

```
wget https://fedorahosted.org/releases/i/b/ibus-typing-booster/ibus-typing-booster-1.2.11.tar.gz

./configure
make
sudo make install
```

it complains about ibus version

```
checking for IBUS... no
configure: error: Package requirements (ibus-1.0 >= 1.1.0) were not met:

No package 'ibus-1.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables IBUS_CFLAGS
and IBUS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

but I have latest ibus

```
$ ibus version
IBus 1.5.5
```

---

Update 2:

after adding one more package called libibus, I am able to continue.

```
sudo apt-get install libibus-1.0-dev
```

But getting an error while making install:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/ibus-typing-booster-1.2.7$ sudo make install
Making install in engine
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/ibus-typing-booster-1.2.7/engine'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/ibus-typing-booster-1.2.7/engine'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/libexec'
 /usr/bin/install -c ibus-engine-typing-booster '/usr/local/libexec'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/ibus/component'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 typing-booster.xml '/usr/local/share/ibus/component'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/ibus-typing-booster/engine'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 factory.py main.py hunspell_table.py hunspell_suggest.py tabsqlitedb.py itb_util.py '/usr/local/share/ibus-typing-booster/engine'
../py-compile: Missing argument to --destdir.
Makefile:400: recipe for target 'install-engine_tablePYTHON' failed
make[2]: *** [install-engine_tablePYTHON] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/ibus-typing-booster-1.2.7/engine'
Makefile:539: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/ibus-typing-booster-1.2.7/engine'
Makefile:482: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: similar question asked here ... http://askubuntu.com/questions/627432/how-to-install-ibus-typing-booster

Comment: No answer for this question was accepted. Were you able to solve your problem? Do you use ibus typing booster, or did you switch to a different solution?

Comment: I was not able to install the software on Ubuntu.

Comment: what error did you when you tried to install it?

Answer (score 2):

To install on Ubuntu you should follow the indications given in the development section of the site.
[Typing booster Development](http://mike-fabian.github.io/ibus-typing-booster/development.html)

As a short reminder here,

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib/ibus
make
make check # optional
make install
```

Required:

- ibus >= 1.5.3
- libm17n-0
- m17n-db
- python3 >= 3.3
- python3-dbus
- python3-xdg

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is there under the name [lp:ibus-typing-booster.](https://code.launchpad.net/ibus-typing-booster)

Comment: I have downloaded the code from bazar. How do I install it? # bzr branch lp:ibus-typing-booster

Answer (score 0):

According to [ibus-typing-booster official site](http://www.typingbooster.org/howtoinstall/), there is an entry for ubuntu in "How to install" section, but unfortunate seems not working.

But anyway you can download the `rpm` package and try to convert to `deb` using [alien](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto).

Install alien:

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

Converting the RPM file to a Debian package

```
sudo alien package_file.rpm
```

Installing the converted Debian package

```
sudo dpkg -i package_file.deb
```

---

EDIT:

Thanks to wilf comment

you can find the source code from https://fedorahosted.org/releases/i/b/ibus-typing-booster/

Download it, compile then install.

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: You don't need to convert RPMs - the files @ https://fedorahosted.org/ibus-typing-booster/ are tar.gz source packages and can be compiled and installed :)