# Building and installing ibus-typing-booster on Ubuntu

Tags: compiling, 19.04, ibus

### Context

I'm trying to install ibus-typing-booster for Hindi:

- Downloaded the source from https://github.com/mike-fabian/ibus-typing-booster/archive/2.6.4.zip
- Checked & satisfied all dependencies: `ibus >= 1.5.3, libm17n-0, m17n-db, python3 >= 3.3, python3-dbus, python3-xdg`
- Executed the commands:

  ```
  ./autogen.sh
  ./configure --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib/ibus
  make
  make check
  make install
  ```
- Here is the build log: http://p.ip.fi/96W1 *Everything seems ok*

---

### Issue

**But** I cannot see the *`ibus-typing-booster preferences`* in the Applications, all that is new is an [emoji picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB1bX.jpg)

I rebooted the system and tried to get [this *(Typing Booster)*](https://www.2daygeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/install-ibus-typing-booster-in-linux-5.png) or [this *(Hunspell)*](https://dann3217.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/wp_post_typingbooster_inputsources.jpg?w=584&h=396) but instead got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eTi8.jpg)
none of which give suggestions while typing.

---

[My system info](http://p.ip.fi/AO8Y), [ibus info](http://p.ip.fi/yhVg)

---

**Footnote**

Related: [install ibus-typing-booster on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642267/) (for which some links in the answer section are either broken or retired).

### What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Feel free to edit, if you see improvements that can be made instead of down voting :)

Comment: Questions are considered as duplicates when situation is same and one of the answer worked for you. Also, there's nothing like "website authorities". This is a community driven site. I have edited your question to remove those things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ibus-typing-booster* is now available in Ubuntu repositories in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

Install ibus-m17n and ibus-typing-booster with dependencies.

In Settings > Region & Languages > Manage installed languages > language support >

1. install/remove language> select desired languages > apply
2. select ibus from the dropdown menu under Keyboard Input Method System

In Region Language > Input Sources > add an input source > three vertical dots > search with keyword "other" --> select other --> add typing booster from the list

Select typing booster keyboard in input source --> settings/preferences --> add the required dictionaries and input methods