# Avro phonetic isn't working on Ubuntu 20.04 for bengali typing

Tags: keyboard-layout, ibus, input-language, system-language, ibus-avro

I have installed avro from official ubuntu store ( also tried installing it by using

> sudo apt install ibus-avro

)

Still not getting desire output.

Please have a look at the first image

[image: Bangla (avro phonetic) is missing from the list]

If I choose Bangla or Bangla (India) or Bangla (Bangladesh) , in that case normal bengali layout is added instead of phonetic keyword.

Any solution is appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Normal bengali layout keyword is added]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "official Ubuntu store". Doing `sudo apt install ibus-avro` gives you the tool from the Ubuntu archive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Avro Keyboard in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280905/how-to-install-avro-keyboard-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue by this steps

1. Logout your profile
2. Login
3. Now try the same method avro phonetic will appear

If still not resolved then restart your computer , then repeat the steps and it will work.

Comment: See if it is available in ibus-typing-booster    https://askubuntu.com/a/1311454/249441

Comment: @Oppili: It's not. `ibus-avro` is a separate IBus plugin for Avro Phonetic.

Comment: There is one phonetic keyboard Phonetic-Bla available in typing booster, check whether it is for  Bangla Language. Seen somewhere else that a bangla/bengali package included in ibus-typing-booster